# Detecting Falls on Android

Tags: java, android, accelerometer

I'm trying to add a feature to my Android app that is able to signal an alert when a user falls on the ground.  My best guess towards approaching this problem is to simply check whether the values for the phone's accelerometer indicate rapid movement.  Is anyone aware of any other more precise ways of approaching this problem?

Comment: It is an interesting use case, but you have to keep in mind that checking all this sensors all the time might drown the battery. Also, newer android versions have a strict way regarding background processes, so you might not be able to access them all the time.

Answer (score 0):

For something like this, there's a high impact in the event of a false alarm so you'd likely want to include a number of conditions in your flagging of a falling event.

Rotation of the phone may also be something to consider, if you notice rapid acceleration in combination with a rotation of the phone from vertical to horizontal or vice versa that might get you better results.

Rapid movement wouldn't itself be indicative of falling, but aside from rotation I can't think of many other built in sensors that would be useful for this.  I suppose you could look for gravitational acceleration and sudden deceleration when a person hits the floor, but that would be difficult to distinguish between a human falling and dropping the phone.

Comment: "but that would be difficult to distinguish between a human falling and dropping the phone. " Just to add to this; using a combination of sensors you could probably see a difference between the two. A phone is usually dropped straight down, whereas someone falling will move in a horizontal direction as well.